# Error: None of the 'n' overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, overloading

I'm getting the above error, but as far as I can tell I've matched my argument list exactly.

Code:

```
void lorentzTransform(std::list<point2P1D>& vol, const vector2D& v) {
    std::list<point2P1D> temp = std::list<point2P1D>();

    for (const point2P1D& pt : vol) {
        point2P1D test = lorentzTransform(pt, v); //Error here.
        temp.push_back(test);
    }

    vol.swap(temp);
}

point2P1D lorentzTransform(const point2P1D& pt, const vector2D& vel);
```

Comment: Post the exact compiler error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I seem to have solved the problem, and didn't keep a save of the problem. I'm not sure what I did - I changed a function that was used by lorentzTransform(const point2P1D&, const vector2D&).

Answer (score 2):

The overload you want to call might not actually visible of the point of calling. The prototype you show must be placed above the other function.

I'm also very worried about that reference return type. I consider it very likely that you return a dangling reference there.

Comment: The prototype is in my *.h file, which is included, yes. And point - I've removed the reference.